# Is it possible for an asp.net MVC "Action Method" to receive JSON without declaring its specific type on the parameter? If so, how?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

So, it pretty much is all in the title. Basically, I want to send a JSON through JQuery from client to asp.net MVC. I'm wondering if it's possible for it to receive (but not necessarily parse) **any** JSON I want to send from JQuery Ajax call, regardless of it's type.. without me having a concrete type/model representation of it. (basically like a dynamic type?)

Doing this the regular way (with me declaring the passing argument as type Object) just brings about nulls, which was what I expected.

Basically, I want to do some kind of "reflection for JSON" type stuff when I receive it, and be able to get it's properties through some kind of foreach loop and etc.

Thanks in advance. Any help would be great!

Comment: what about receiving an object? you could alternately have no parameters and inspect request...

Comment: you mean a JSON object? how would you go about that? Basically, my goal is to see how MVC would parse the JSON object i'm sending, and be able to dynamically get it's properties and values through a foreach loop or something without a concrete c# type for it.

Comment: no I mean `public ActionResult Index(object thing){` receive an object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use an `IDictionary<string, object>` as action argument. Just write a custom model binder that will parse a JSON request into it:

```
public class DictionaryModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (!controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType.StartsWith("application/json", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return null;
        }

        controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream))
        {
            var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
            {
                return null;
            }
            return new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(json);
        }
    }
}
```

which will be registered in `Application_Start`:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(IDictionary<string, object>), new DictionaryModelBinder());
```

then you could have the following controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(IDictionary<string, object> model)
{
    return Json(model);
}
```

to which you can throw anything:

```
var model = {
    foo: {
        bar: [ 1, 2, 3 ],
        baz: 'some baz value'
    }
};

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("foo")',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    success: function (result) {
        // TODO: process the results from the server
    }
});
```

Comment: that seems more complicated than what I did in the past for the same thing (different computer, not this one)

Comment: @jcolebrand, what did you do in the past?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: this is awesome. lots of things going on here. thanks

Comment: @jcolebrand: i'm curious too. i tried Object as type before but it (instance) returned null when I passed json to it.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I'm going to have to wait till Tuesday to look it up ;-)

Comment: @JanCarloViray I'm curious you couldn't get to some part of it in the request dictionary ... or did you try that at all?

Comment: @jcolebrand I remember I tried changing the type to Object but I couldn't parse anything out of it (worked on a concrete type though) Maybe I did something wrong. I'll try it again when I get the chance..

Comment: Im getting a 500 error when I do this? It obviously doesnt like my parameter on the action method?

Comment: Should the binder be registered in `Application_Start()` in `Global.asax`?
 Because I didn't see any defined classes in `App_Start` Folder for the binders