# Pass dynamic data to mvc controller with AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, dynamic

How can I pass `dynamic` data with an `AJAX` call to an `MVC` `Controller`?

`Controller`:

```
public JsonResult ApplyFilters(dynamic filters){
   return null;
}
```

The `AJAX` call:

```
$(':checkbox').click(function (event) {
    var serviceIds = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).toArray();

    //alert(serviceIds);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/home/ApplyFilters',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            name: serviceIds
        }),
        contentType: 'application/json',

        success: function (data) {
            alert("succeeded");
        },
        error: function (err, data) {
            alert("Error " + err.responseText);
        }
    });

    //return false;
});
```

Ideally would be that the `filters` would contain the `serviceIds` as a property

For example like this: `filters.ServiceIds`.
I got another filter for a date range and that one would be added like so: `filters.DateRange`.

And server side get the filter as a `dynamic` object in the `ApplyFilters()`

Comment: What does the filters object look, if your call the action with the AJAX call?

Comment: It looks like this: {object} and it can't be expanded.

Comment: `dynamic` objects are evaluated at the run time so change the return to `return Json(filters)` so that you can see the actual data returned in the response.

Comment: True, but I can just cast it too since I already know what type the `object` is. But that's failing because some how the data isn't passed 'good'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ad far as i know the [default ASP MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) model binder cannot accomplish such a thing.

Fortunately there are numerous solutions, here are two of them :

**1**. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687110/is-it-possible-for-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-to-receive-json-without-declar) is the first one, it converts your JSON data into a `IDictionary<string, object>` instance before passing it to your controller action. You would end up with :

```
public JsonResult ApplyFilters(IDictionary<string, object> filters)
{
   return null;
}
```

**2**. The [second approach](http://www.amazedsaint.com/2011/02/aspnet-mvc-dynamic-json-jquery.html) enables your controller action to receive a [JsonValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.json.jsonvalue%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) instance. Making your action looks like this one :

```
public JsonResult ApplyFilters([DynamicJson]JsonValue filters)
{
   return null;
}
```

**3**. Based on the previous tutorials, you could create your own custom model binder returning a dynamic object. The following code has been taken from the first proposal and modified to generate a dynamic object. It is just to illustrate the idea, don't use it as is :

```
public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    if (!controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType.StartsWith("application/json", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        return null;
    }

    controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream))
    {
        var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
        {
            return null;
        }
        dynamic result = new ExpandoObject();
        var deserializedObject = new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(json) as IDictionary<string, object>;
        if (deserializedObject != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in deserializedObject)
            {
                ((IDictionary<string, object>)result).Add(item.Key, item.Value);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

These solutions rely on building a custom model binder to handle this particuliar scenario :

- Custom model binder is just an implementation of the [IModelBinder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.mvc.imodelbinder%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) interface in charge of parsing JSON posted data and converting them into another format.
- ASP MVC framework is told to use these specific custom model binders by registering them (with `ModelBinders.Binders.Add` or using a dedicated attribute ([CustomModelBinderAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.mvc.custommodelbinderattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)).

Comment: But I have seen this working exactly as how I described it in another project I have worked on. So I know this is possible for a 100%!

Comment: But doesn't the client side code needs a code refactor for it to work?

Comment: These custom model binders are expecting and parsing JSON. And it's exactly what you're providing to the server with your assignment "data: JSON.stringify({ name: serviceIds })". So no client code refactor should be required.